# (500) Backend Error on update style id by Google Fusion Table REST API

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I am updating Fusiontable style by REST api.

But I got error with **(500) Backend Error** message.
Where on the same time I got successful message in fusiontable insert/update row by REST api.

How can I debug/resolve the issue.

Here is my code:

```
$columnName = self::getStyleColumnPrefix($style_id);
$strokeOpacity = '1';
$fillOpacity = '1';
$kind = 'fusiontables#fromColumn';
$tableId = $this->table;
$styleId = $style_id;

$fillColorStyler = new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleFunction();
$fillColorStyler->setColumnName($columnName);
$fillColorStyler->setKind($kind);

$polygonOptions = new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_PolygonStyle();
$polygonOptions->setFillColorStyler($fillColorStyler);
$polygonOptions->setStrokeOpacity($strokeOpacity);
$polygonOptions->setFillOpacity($fillOpacity);

$postBody = new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleSetting();
$postBody->setPolygonOptions($polygonOptions);

// $this->service = new \Google_Service_Fusiontables_Style_Resource();
$results = $this->service->style->update($tableId, $styleId, $postBody);
```

I am getting error in last line

> $results = $this->service->style->update($tableId, $styleId, $postBody);

**Stack trace**

> ```
> File:
> D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php:110
> Message:
> Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/tables/1ycoFAd3BrVZ248zXausz4kKe66Jj3fZDeKvxlBMy/styles/1: (500) Backend Error
> Stack trace:
> @0 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
> @1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
> @2 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Task\Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> @3 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
> @4 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(590): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
> @5 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(237): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
> @6 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Service\Fusiontables.php(904): Google_Service_Resource->call('update', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
> @7 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\module\BenchMarking\src\BenchMarking\Model\FusionTableModel.php(494): Google_Service_Fusiontables_Style_Resource->update('1ycoFAd3BrVZ248...', 1, Object(Google_Service_Fusiontables_StyleSetting))
> @8 D:\xampp2\htdocs\itp-benchmarking\branches\development\module\BenchMarking\src\BenchMarking\Controller\FusionTableController.php(268): BenchMarking\Model\FusionTableModel->setStyleIdOfMeasure(1)
> ```

I am using google-api-php-client (v1.1).

Comment: Getting the same when trying to insert a style (v2, ASP.NET client). Did you find anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't set both a `colorStyler` *and* other properties like `strokeOpacity`. When I removed the latter, I no longer received the error.

It's currently not documented and the API error response should definitely be clearer on the matter...